# Is there any difference between a maximal regular left ideal and a regular maximal left ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I am aware of the lemma that every regular left ideal of a ring is contained in a maximal left ideal that is regular. 
But still things are not very clear. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes regular in the sense of Jacobson.

Comment: Regular in the sense of Jacobson?  (for $L$ a left ideal, there exists $e$ such that $x-xe\in L$ for all $x\in R$?)

Comment: Sorry, I  typoed the definition earlier: corrected by reposting my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the subset of maximal left ideals which are regular. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the set of elements which are maximal in the poset of (proper) regular left ideals.

Obviously $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{B}$, but the question is whether or not the reverse containment holds.

From the definition, we know that any left ideal containing a regular left ideal is automatically regular.  So an element of $\mathcal{B}$ cannot be properly contained in a maximal left ideal, because that would also have to be regular as well.  So yes, $\mathcal B\subseteq \mathcal A$ as well.

Comment: Got it. Thanks :)